# How to scroll to the bottom or to the beginning of a terminal session in xterm?

Tags: xterm, scrolling

If I want to move up or down in `xterm` page by page I do it with `<shift> + <PgUp>` and `<shift> + <PgDn>`. But how can I completely move to the bottom or to the beginning of the terminal session without going one page at a time?

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, there is no default way to jump to the top, but the easiest way to jump to the bottom is to type anything (beside the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp/Down</kbd> of course).

For jumping at the top, you can map e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to scroll up 1000pages by starting `xterm` with

```
xterm -xrm  "XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \n Shift <Key>Home: scroll-back(1000)\n"
```

or adding

```
XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \n\
   Shift <Key>Home: scroll-back(1000)
```

to your `$HOME/.Xresources` (you need to restart your XServer or call `xkrdb -merge $HOME/.Xresources` to activate it).

For jumping additionally to the end with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, use

```
xterm*vt100.translations: #override \n\
 Shift <Key>Home: scroll-back(1000) \n\
 Shift <Key>End: scroll-forw(1000)
```

Comment: I disabled that option with `XTerm*vt100.scrollTtyOutput: false` because I sometimes wanted to scroll up while the system was updating but couldn't do it for the constant output.

Comment: @Santaru72 I extended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Getting to the top or bottom in a comprehensive terminal session can be done with default `xterm` in less than a few seconds with the **scrollbar active**. Unfortunately, due to the poor documentation, this is very hard to find. (Took me over half an hour in searching, so this is why I'd like to share it here).

You've probably wondered that when you have the scrollbar on, dragging the scrollbar with the left button does absolutely nothing (except for showing you that stupid arrow in one direction).

The solution is to use the **middle mouse button** with it.

Grab the scrollbar, click on it with middle button and don't release middle button until you've arrived at the position you intended to end up.
If you really want to perform an **immediate** jump to bottom or top of your terminal session, do **not** drag, but **click** the middle button on the very top respectively bottom. (Of course, this will only work if the mouse cursor is *within* the area of the scrollbar; otherwise the middle button will work as *'Paste text'*.)

P.S. Since the left button won't do anything at all anyway with the scrollbar position marker, it escapes me why this was not assigned to the left button by default? Would have been a lot more logical, and perhaps even easier to handle.

Comment: Not sure why you think it does nothing.  By default right button scrolls up, left button scrolls down.  Both do so by an amount based on position in the bar (scrolls by number of lines between the top and the cursor). Perhaps something is intercepting in your case.

Comment: No, I was unclear. I mean to press left button on the position marker in the scrollbar and __hold it__, then, while still holding it, try to move the mouse up and down. *This* will do nothing in fact, unlike in other OSes with terminal programs, where this would normally work the way *I* expect it to. But using the middle button instead of the left one for the very same operation *does* work.

Answer (score 1):

[Since 2018](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_331), XTerm provides this action ([manual page, ACTIONS section](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:scroll-to)):

```
scroll-to(count)
    Scroll to the given line relative to the beginning of the saved-lines. For instance,
    "scroll-to(0)" would scroll to the beginning. Two special nonnumeric parameters are
    recognized:

    scroll-to(begin)
        Scroll to the beginning of the saved lines.

    scroll-to(end)
        Scroll to the end of the saved lines, i.e., to the currently active page.
```

To make <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> scroll to the top and
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> to the bottom, add this to `~/.Xresources`:

```
XTerm*vt100.Translations: #override\
  Shift <KeyPress> Home:  scroll-to(begin) \n\
  Shift <KeyPress> End:   scroll-to(end) \n\
```

Issue `xrdb ~/.Xresources` and open a new XTerm and the binding should be working.